# How i fixed $data is undefined?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

I have a problem while creating edit and create forms
I have a form that is used to create and edit when I call $data on the form so that it appears when editing the form.

But when I open the form to create new data the error ***$data is undefined*** appears.

This is my route

```
Route::resource('/tabungan/jadwal-autodebet', SavingAccountScheduleController::class);
```

This is the create and edit script in my controller

```
public function create()
{

    $info['header'] = $this->title;
    $info['description'] = 'Tambah';
    $info['breadcrumb'] = null;
    return view('banking::autodebet-schedule.form',$info);
}

public function edit($id)
{

    $info['header'] = $this->title;
    $info['description'] = 'Ubah';
    $info['breadcrumb'] = null;

    $data = TransactionSchedule::find($id);

    $origin = clone $data;
    $origin = $data->origin;
    
    $destination = clone $data;
    $destination = $data->destination;

    $destinationType = '';
    $saving = SavingAccount::class;
    $loan = LoanAccount::class;
    if($data->origin_type == $saving){
        $destinationType = 'Tabungan';
    }elseif($data->origin_type == $loan){
        $destinationType = 'Pinjaman';
    }
    // dd($data,$origin,$destination);

    return view('banking::autodebet-schedule.form',compact('data','origin','destination','destinationType'),$info);
}
```

and this is my ***autodebet.schedule.form*** script

```
<form id="formData" action="{{ isset($data) ? admin_url('cb/tabungan/jadwal-autodebet/'.$data->id) : admin_url('cb/tabungan/jadwal-autodebet/')}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            @if(isset($data))
                {{method_field('PUT')}}
            @endif
            <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">                    
                <div class="col-12">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <label class="label-required" for="" >Produk Tujuan</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                        <select name="destination_type" id="destination_type" class="select2 form-control destination_type">
                                <option value="{{ $data->origin_type }}">{{ $destinationType }}</option>
                                <option class="type_option" id="SavingAccount" value="Modules\Banking\Entities\SavingAccount">Tabungan</option>
                                <option class="type_option" id="LoanAccount" value="Modules\Banking\Entities\LoanAccount">Pinjaman</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <label class="label-required" for="">No Rekening Sumber</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <select id="origin_code" class="select2 form-control origin_code">
                                        <option value="{{ $origin->id }}">{{ $origin->saving_code }}-{{ $origin->customer->customer_name}}-{{ $destinationType }}</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <label class="label-required" for="" >Transaksi Rekening Anggota/Nasabah Lain</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                        <input type="hidden" id="other_costumer_transaction" name="other_costumer_transaction" value="0">
                            <div class="az-toggle {{ 'off' }}" id="other_costumer_transaction_toggle"><span></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <label class="label-required" for="">No Rekening Tujuan</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <select id="destination_code" class="select2 form-control destination_code" >
                            <option value="{{ $destination->id }}">{{ $destination->saving_code }}-{{ $destination->customer->customer_name}}-{{ $destinationType }}</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row" id="info-nasabah" style="display: none">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <h6>No. Rekening : <span id="info-kode">xxx.xxx.xxx</span></h6>
                        </div>
                    

                    
                        <div class="col-2">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <h6>Nama Nasabah : <span id="info-nama">xxx.xxx.xxx</span></h6>
                        </div>
                    

                    
                        <div class="col-2">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <h6>Tipe Produk : <span id="info-produk">xxx.xxx.xxx</span></h6>
                        </div>
                    

                    
                        <div class="col-2">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <h6>Saldo : <span id="info-saldo">xxx.xxx.xxx</span></h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <label class="label-required" for="">Tanggal Autodebet</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <select name="scheduled_day" id="scheduled_day" class="select2 form-control scheduled_day">
                                <option disabled value="{{ $data->scheduled_day }}">{{ $data->scheduled_day }}</option>
                                @for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
                                    <option class="day_option" id="day_{{ $i }}" value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                                @endfor
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <label for="saving_type_package">Keterangan</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <textarea name="desc" class="form-control desc" id="" cols="30" rows="5">{{ $data->desc }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <label class="label-required" for="" >Status Autodebet</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                        <input type="hidden" id="transaction_schedule_status" name="transaction_schedule_status" value="{{ $data->transaction_schedule_status ?? 1 }}">
                            <div class="az-toggle {{ isset($data->transaction_schedule_status) ? ($data->transaction_schedule_status == 1 ? 'on' :'') : 'on' }}" id="autodebet_status_toggle"><span></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <input type="hidden" value="" id="origin_id" name="origin_id">
                    <input type="hidden" class="schedule_id" id="schedule_id" name="schedule_id">
                    <input type="hidden" name="destination_code" id="destination_code_input">
                    <input type="hidden" name="origin_code" id="origin_code_input">
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="float-right">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a href="{{admin_url('cb/tabungan/jadwal-autodebet')}}">
                                        <button id="back_button" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"><i class="typcn typcn-times"></i>Batalkan</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>                                    
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button id="submit_button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                                        <i id="loading_icon" style="display: none" class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>
                                        <i id="submit_icon" class="typcn typcn-input-checked"></i>
                                        Simpan</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                </div>                    
            </div>
            </form>
```

how i fixed this problem?

Comment: That's probably due to the places in your template where you access $data directly, without having it wrapped into an isset.

Comment: Including your whole project doesn't focus on the issue. You need to decide what it is your having a problem with, and if you decide you are unable to fix it, include only code that has to do with the part you can't figure out, or don't understand.